# How to perform 64-bit division on hardware with only 32-bit support?

Tags: math, arm

I'm writing bare-metal program for RP2040 (ARM Cortex M0+ cores). This chip has hardware for 32-bit integer division, but don't have one for 64-bit. I'm looking for algorithm to use (if possible) 32/32 integer division to perform 64/64 division. Please don't write answers like "use compiler runtime libraries". I want to understand algorithm and write one by my own without using third-party solutions.

I've tried to use standard "long division" algorithm and it works fine, but I'm not sure if this approach is optimal when we have relative fast 32/32 division method.

Comment: can you clarify on the "standard" long division approach you are using?  A base 2 or base 10 long division would be sub optimal, but a base 2^32 divison would leverage a fast 32/32 division nicely

Comment: I'm using base 2 approach. I will try to implement base 2^32.

Comment: My approach would be to compile a simple c program which has a function which divides a uint64 by a uint64 and then check out the assembly it generates. I was going to do it, but it appears compiling for ARM Cortex m0 is a bit more involved than I thought.

Comment: You typically want the base of your long division to be such that you can multiply two "digits" without too much issue. If you have access to a 32 bit multiplication that provides 64 bits of result, perhaps in two variables / registers, then using that is fine. Otherwise using base 2^16 would still give you a significant speed boost over base 2 but would allow you to perform multiplication with carry while staying within 32 bit arithmetic.

Comment: There is also the context.  Is either operand constant (over a loop) or it is just two variable operands to the division all the time.

Comment: Leveraging 32-bit division is possible, but involved. The problem is that it's relatively easy to divide u64 or u128 by u32, where as computing `u64 / (u32_hi << 32 + u32_lo)` with just the top 32 bit of the denominator gives a range of possible values (or fewer than 32 correct bits). How involved it is? Well -- Pentium  used approximation tables to split floating point division in fewer steps and failed on the first attempt.